# Cause an exception "ReadOnly controls collection" in Krypton toolkit

Tags: winforms, krypton-toolkit

I have integrated krypton toolkit in my winforms project.everything is working fine, but after I move in VS 2015 I got error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe its some sort of bug with group boxes ( assuming thats what it is), where VS doesn't treat the groupbox as a panel or something. I see you commented out something related below it.

Try:

```
this.kryptonHeaderGroup_EmailSupplementBy.Panel.Controls.Add(this.yourcontrolname);
```

Where the control is a member of the group.